Is there another way to say instead of saying "make me"?
I watched a film and in the film, a man forced a woman to leave his office but the woman refused to do that. Then he threatened the woman more but she said "make me".
I did a study. It seems like you say "make me" when you refuse to do something when someone make you do it. And, "make me" seems like slang.
Is there another way to say (that doesn't sound like slang) instead of saying "make me"?

"forced someone to leave" means succeeded in having someone leave.  To "make someone do something" is to succeed in having them do it.  Those phrases cannot be used of  attempts.  You could say "Tried to force her to leave" or "Tried to make her leave".

Are you asking "Is there something that woman could have said in that particular situation that would have been more formal?"

Sure. "Make me" means, "You have ordered me to do X. I don't believe you have the power to force me to do it. So I defy you to force me."
It is informal. In a more formal setting, you would use a longer, more explicit statement. Like, "I challenge you to try to force me to do that." Or, "I do not believe you have the power to force me to do that." Or, "You do not have the authority to compel me to do that." Etc. One could word it many ways. People say "make me" because it is very concise.

And note per @TimR’s comment the distinction in the paraphrase: you have ordered me on one hand, but on the other, I don’t believe you have the power to force me.
